# Django - A Variable to Check in Base Template That Is Modified By View Functions

Tags: python, django

Whaat I Want To Do:
Have a Boolean Variable: has_sidebar to check if I should include the sidebar partial or not

The partial is called in base.html, my base template

view functions should be able to change has_sidebar to declare whether response will be rendered with sidebar or not.

```
#views.py
def my_func1(request):
   has_sidebar = True
   return render_to_response('template1.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def my_func2(request):
   has_sidebar = False
   return render_to_response('template2.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#base.html
{% if has_sidebar %}{%include 'sidebar.html'%}{%endif%}

#template1.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

#template2.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

how can I do this? thanks in advance!

**NOTE**: The HTML layout only allows me to render the sidebar in the base template.

Comment: This is a very basic feature in Django - using a RequestContext to pass a variable into a template. Have you tried it?

Comment: ok. I may have phrased it wrong. all my view actions extend base.html. each of my view actions have different templates aside from base.html. base.html is a "base template", that no view action renders explicitly. see edits

Comment: So what's the problem here ? Just pass has_sidebar in render_to_response and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return base.html to be rendered, add `from django.shortcuts import render_to_response` to the top of your views.py and put the following in both my_funcs:

```
return render_to_response('base.html', {'has_sidebar': has_sidebar})
```